# In what units to quote the thermal Blackbody temperature

Tags: astrophysics, high-energy-astrophysics

Just a quick question relating to the thermal Blackbody temperature of a celestial object. In the c.g.s regime of astrophysics, is it more 'sophisticated' to quote the thermal Blackbody temperature in units of Kelvin ($\mathrm{K}$) or in units of $\mathrm{keV}$? That is to say to use $k_{B}T_{\mathrm{bb}}$ and convert to an energy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but the (Planck's) formula for blackbody radiation is given by

$$S_{\lambda} = \frac{8 \pi h c}{\lambda^5} \frac{1}{e^{hc/\lambda kT} - 1}$$

where $h$ is in $\mathrm{J \cdot s}$, $c$ in $\mathrm{m/s}$, $\lambda$ in $\mathrm{m}$, $k$ in $\mathrm{J/K}$ and $T$ in $\mathrm{K}$.
So, the temperature is just in kelvin, not in energy.
This formula, with these units, gives $S$ in $\mathrm{W/m^2/m}$, which describes the amount of energy per temperature and wavelength. There is no need to convert a given temperature to energy.

Comment: Did you mean to write $\mathrm{W/ m^2/m}$?